# Firmware load fails for every module in busybox 1.32 and linux kernel 5.7.0, but it is OK with same kernel under ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded, busybox, firmware

I'm using busybox 1.32. I've compiled 5.7 kernel in my ubuntu 20.04 development system.
When booting ubuntu, every kernel module is OK, but when booting busybox based image, in every module which needs firmware, loading firmware fails with following message:

```
[    8.755012] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2  
[   12.543489] r8169 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw failed with error -2  
[   12.543494] r8169 0000:04:00.0: Unable to load firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw (-2)  
[  125.508623] si2168 4-0064: Direct firmware load for dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw failed with error -2
```

I've copied all firmware files in `/lib/firmware`. Also firmware load fails both in boot, and after boot when a hardware needs to load firmware.

It seems it is something related to 5.x kernel with busybox, because I've not noticed similar behavior in 4.9 kernel, which I used before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Firmware loading is performed in userspace on behalf of a kernel request.  This is a configurable feature in Busybox.  BTW `-2` is ENOENT, no such file or directory.  Did you preserve the subdirectory hierarchy when you  *"copied all firmware files in /lib/firmware"*?

Comment: Yes, Also most firmwares are in /lib/firmware root, not it's subdirs.

Comment: *"Also most firmwares are in /lib/firmware root, not it's [sic] subdirs"* -- Irrelevant since the first firmware blob that is not found is expected to be in a subdirectory.